# Install Hydro from source: unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, source, wstool, timeout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Hydro from source following [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source) on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.
After this command: `wstool init -j8 src hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall`
I got several errors of this type:

```
TypeError: checkout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

The whole traceback of the command is:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/0844c11ef2688b93b277597b82e087ce

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197398/install-hydro-from-source:-unexpected-keyword-argument-%27timeout%27/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 580 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Judging by the output I have to conclude that you have a version of `vcstools` which does not line up with the version of `wstools` you are using. This might be a case of a `pip` installed version of `vcstools` overlaying the `apt-get` version, see:

http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

You can check by seeing if the output of this:

```
python -c 'import vcstools; print(vcstools.__file__)'
```

Is prefixed with `/usr/local/lib...`. If it is then the default version of `vcstools` is coming from `pip` and not `apt-get`. In which case you'll need to `sudo pip uninstall vcstools` repeatedly until it reports that nothing was uninstalled, then do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-vcstools`. Hopefully that should clear up your issue.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-11-17**:
You were right! Thank you it worked!